# How to force a jupyter notebook to only use packages installed within a virtual environment?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, virtualenv

I am running `Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS` (`4.15.0-58-generic` kernel). I set up a virtual environment with

```
$ virtualenv venv
```

and activated it with

```
$ source venv/bin/activate
```

I installed a few packages

```
(venv) $ pip install numpy matplotlib
```

and then started a jupyter notebook

```
(venv) $ jupyter notebook
```

When I do a `!pip list` from inside a jupyter notebook I get a list of packages which are installed for the whole system and not for this environment. If I close the notebook and do a `(venv) $ pip list` everything is fine (i.e. I get a list of packages installed in the virtual environment).

So my question is, how do I force the Jupyter notebook to only use the packages from the virtual environment from which I started it?

Note that I installed some python packages previously with `sudo pip install`, is that causing my problems here?

Comment: did you get a solution?

Comment: @kosmos no, unfortunately not. Do you happen to have a solution?

Comment: No. Still not able to find a solution.

Answer (score -1):

You have to install a custom kernel

```
(venv) $ pip install ipykernel
(venv) $ ipython kernel install --user --name=projectname
```

After that you can start the notebook and choose the new kernel from the top menu -> kernel -> change kernel

Comment: Not working unfortunately: doing exactly as you suggested, I still get the full list of python packages installed for the system when running `!pip list` from inside the notebook (started inside the virtual environment).